# Centre of cell for sprite collision

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on game in JavaScript using Canvas. The sprite in question moves horizontally OR vertically (but not both) The playing area is divided up in 16 x16 pixel cells (which is the same size as the sprite) for collision. I'm drawing the sprite from the top left (not the centre). I've worked out how to detect if the sprite has crossed over a new cell.

```
var modX = sprite.x % 16;
var modY = sprite.y % 16; 
if (modX == 0 && modY == 0) 
{
    // Sprite has entered new cell. Do appropriate functions
}
```

I now need to work out when the sprite is in the middle of a cell which is giving me a bit of a headache as it's not the same as the above and adding half a cell width.... I was hoping someone might be able to help out with some pseudocode. 
And remember: I'm an artist trying to better myself using javascript - so go easy on me, ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, being in the middle of a cell just mean one remainder is 7 :

```
var modX = sprite.x % 16;
var modY = sprite.y % 16; 
if (modX == 7 || modY == 7) 
{
   // in the middle of a cell 
}
```

But if i may there might be two things to change :
1- handle a grid offset so you can decide of your game layout.
2- remember the cell you just came in the center of not to do things twice

```
// somewhere in the init of the game ...//
var gridX = 0, gridY = 0;
var lastCenterCol = -1, lastCenterRow = -1;

// in your game loop //
var modX   = (sprite.x - gridX )% 16;
var modY   = (sprite.y - gridY )% 16;
var column = (sprite.x - gridX  - modX) / 16;
var row    = (sprite.y- gridY - modY) / 16;

if ( (column!=lastCenterCol) && (row!=lastCenterRow) &&  ( (modX == 7) || (modY == 7) ) ) 
{
  lastCenterCol=column;
  lastCenterRow=row;
  // Sprite just entered this cell center.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks fellas. I finally worked out where I'd being wrong; and it wasn't my maths! When the sprite is in the top left he's actually at 24,16 and not 16,16 as previously thought. So you could imagine why things weren't working.

Comment: ok, nice you found. I was wondering if you were having offset issues, that's why i added the offset part in my reply. Yo !

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head I would do the same as you

```
var modX1 = sprite.x%8;
var modY1 = sprite.y%8;

var modX2 = sprite.x%16;
var modY2 = sprite.y%16;

if ((modX1 == 0) && (modY1 == 0) && (modX2 != 0) && (modY2 != 0))
{
    //sprite is in the center of the tile...
}
```

Simply check if it divides by 8, which is half of your cell then make sure it doesn't divide by 16 which is the edge of your cell.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better create a Grid and add the sprite to it. This helps a lot and is a lot more faster. Here is my article on Java-Gaming.Org

- [Using Grids For Collisions](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/using-grids-for-collisions/29244/view.html)

The implementation language is Java but you can easily translate it into JavaScript.